# Conditional dependency on value for nested objects json schema

Tags: python, c#, json, .net, jsonschema

```
{
  "submitOrderRequest": {
    "requestHeader": {
      "companyCode": "MSD Code",
      "accountNumber": "989898989",
      "billingLanguage": "EN",
      "operation": "NewActivation"
    },
    "requestBody": {
      "device": [
        {
          "lineID": "4",
          "parentLineID": "0",
          "sku": "IP1264WHT",
          "quantity": "1",
          "WirelessOptions": [
            {
              "optionsSocMSF": "169.00",
              "optionsSocType": "REGULAR",
              "optionsSocOneTimeFee": "NO"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to make " "lineID","parentLineID","sku","quantity"" Mandatory based on "operation" property value . The operation has enum defined for it ["enum":"NewActivation","Hardware","Software"] .

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: How to make "lineID","parentLineID","sku","quantity"" Mandatory based on "operation" property value . The operation has enum defined for it ["enum":"NewActivation","Hardware","Software"] .

Comment: Yes, it was alredy said in the question. But it's not clear. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried? And what it means for you to make those fields mendatory?

Comment: Here is pseudo code : 
If (operation=="NewActiavtion" || operation=="Hardware" ) then "lineID","parentLineID","sku","quantity"" are mandatory else "lineID","parentLineID","sku","quantity"" optional
how to achieve this in JSON Schema

Comment: Great! What problems have you faced trying to implement this behaviour?

Comment: I am unable to access the value of operation field in defination

Comment: "allOf": [
 {
"if": {
 "properties": {
    "operation": {
       "$ref": "#/$def/operation",
       "enum": [
            "NewActivation"
       ]
   }
} },
    "then": {
    "required": [
        "lineID",
        "parentLineID",
        "sku",
        "quantity",
        "offerTerm"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
 "if": {
  "properties": {
     "operation": {"$ref": "#/$def/operation","enum": ["HardwareUpgrade"]}
  }},
    "then": {
      "required": [
        "lineID",
        "parentLineID",
        "sku",
        "quantity",
        "offerTerm"
       ]} }
]